# Declaring function which will be used in pthread_create -- confusing syntax error

Tags: c, pthreads

I am trying to define a function which will be used as the thread-start-routine argument to [`pthread_create`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html).  I wrote this:

```
4  void *(*Func)(void*)
5  {
6      pthread_exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
7  }
```

But GCC prints out an error to line 5:

```
error： expected 「=」, 「,」, 「;」, 「asm」 or 「__attribute__」 before 「{」 token
```

What is wrong with this definition?

Comment: I took the liberty of revising this question to make it easier for people with a similar problem to find.  Hope that's ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is with the syntax of your function definition -- the compiler thinks you aren't defining a function at all.

```
void *(*Func)(void*)
{
```

The formal grammar for C says that this is the definition of a *global variable* named `Func`, which is a *pointer to* a function which takes a single `void *` argument and returns `void *`.  This definition is missing its trailing semicolon, and is immediately followed by the beginning of a function body, but no function is being defined, so you get a syntax error.

You probably *thought* you were defining a *function* named `Func`, and making its type match the thread-start-routine argument to `pthread_create`.  This is one of the places where C declarator syntax gets very confusing -- there is a logic to it, but for right now please just take my word for it that you need to write

```
void *Func(void *unused) // in C++, but not in C, "unused" may be omitted
{
   pthread_exit(0); // or, equivalently, "return 0;"
}
```

and then you can do

```
pthread_create(&PID, 0, Func, 0);
```

without any additional hoop-jumping, even though the two declarations do not look exactly the same.

(FYI, it's harmless, but technically `EXIT_SUCCESS` should not be used with `pthread_exit`.)

Answer (score 4):

The problem isn't `pthread_create`,

```
void *(*Func)(void*)
{
   pthread_exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

is not a valid function definition. It's actually the signature of the function pointer `&func`. You probably want:

```
void* func(void* parameter)
{
   pthread_exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```